# XtraReport Export Excel and Print with Page Header

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

Hy,
I have an `XtraReport` and I want to export to an Excel File
after that I need to print it , but I loose all the page formats (Header , Footer , Repeat on each Page ... )

```
    string reportPath = "c:\\Test.xls";

    // Create a report instance.
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    reportDS c = new reportDS();
    c.Init();

    // genereaza report
    report.DataSource = new reportDS[] { c };

    // Get its XLS export options.
    XlsExportOptions xlsOptions = report.ExportOptions.Xls;

    // Set XLS-specific export options.
    xlsOptions.ShowGridLines = true;
    xlsOptions.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Value;

    // Export the report to XLS.
    report.ExportToXls(reportPath);

    // Show the result.
    StartProcess(reportPath);
```

Can you tell me if it's possible what I want to do ?
And if not , can you suggest me another method ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just learned the reporting tools for an hour or so. But I think you should add PageHeader and PageFooter to the report and put all your header and footer there. When you export it, they will be on the document then. I've tried it.

Comment: If you export it to PDF , yes .. the headers / footer are all ok, but if you export into Excel , I lose all page formats (when I'm trying to print the document)